# Оборот "Прежде(,) чем"

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли я расставила запятые: "Прежде(,) чем технический регламент ТС вступает в силу, он должен пройти стадию публичных обсуждений"?
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно ставить, а можно и не ставить. Подобный вопрос был по поводу союза "потому что"

Answer (score 3):

В абсолютном начале предложения сложные союзы обычно запятыми не разделяются.